# Combining Polygons in a Graph

Tags: python, algorithm, math, data-structures, polygon

I am currently working on a small project that requires me to calculate the Union of 2 or more given rectangles. The catch here is that the after combining the rectangles into a polygon, the result must be given in the form of rectangles.  See this image for reference:

[image: Reference Image]

The condition for the Rectangle is as follows:

The rectangle must intersect the y-axis and the
the bottom-right corner must lie strictly to the right and strictly below the top-left corner.

Here is my logic to solve the problem:

- Split the list of Rectangles in the middle.
- Find Intersecting rectangles to create a polygon.
- Recursivly run the for all the rectangles to be converted into polygons.
- Combine all the polygons into a single unit to find a single large polygon.
- Try spliting up the polygon into rectangles to solve the given implementation.

I tried creating a set of all possible points in the rectangles but it was consuming too much memory not idle for the application. All of my code has been listed as follows:

```py
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int) -> None:
    
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_coordinates(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:

        return (self.x, self.y)
    

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
 
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
        return False
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))


class Rectangle:
    
    top_left: Point
    bottom_right: Point

    def __init__(self, top_left: Point, bottom_right: Point) -> None:
       
        if top_left.x < 0 and bottom_right.x > 0:
            self.top_left = top_left
            self.bottom_right = bottom_right
        else:
            raise ValueError("Rectangle must intersect Y-axis")
    
        

    def contains(self, point: Point) -> bool:
       
        if self.top_left.x <= point.x <= self.bottom_right.x and self.bottom_right.y <= point.y <= self.top_left.y:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        

    def get_points(self) -> Tuple[Point, Point]:
        return (self.top_left, self.bottom_right)
```

I am not sure of what the ideal approach should be while solving this problem. I think the divide and conquer approach should be ideal in solving this but am not sure How to implement. For reference this is how the Union class looks right now:

```py
class Union:
    rectangles: List[Rectangle]
    def __init__(self, rectangles: List[Rectangle]) -> None:
          self.rectangles = rectangles
    
     def get_union(self) -> List[Rectangle]:
     """
        Returns a list of Points representing the coordinates of the union.
        Rectangles should be returned in a sorted order from top to bottom.
        :return: The Rectangles from top to bottom that make up the intersection.
        """
```

Comment: Seems sorting rectangles by the top Y and using horizontal sweep line might help.

Comment: @MBo Using Horizontal sweep is consuming more memory than the system can afford.

Comment: Moving horizontal line, we have to store "active" rectangles, so needed memory is not larger than source size.

Comment: Can you help me with an implementation of what you are meaning? Like I understand it but not sure how to implement it in code.

Comment: Hi! Six months later, I'm curious: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes Stef I managed to figure it out. Your solution helped a lot. It was for a DSA class I was taking and this between yours, MBo and parts of mine I was able to figure it out. I really wish I could find the solution that I implemented but I don’t have it. P.S: Didn’t open Stack for months but You actually deserved credit for it.

Comment: Hi! Did you complete your project? Did you end up merging the rectangles the way suggested here or did you end up changing approaches completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see a divide and conquer approach to solve this. It doesn't mean that it doesn't exist, but I don't know how two sets of sliced rectangles, as shown on the right of your figure, could be easily combined.

I would prefer a recursive approach: considering N rectangles already combined, we can add a new rectangle by analysing how it intersects each of the existing rectangles. There, we need to evaluate every possible case:

- is the intersection included in the existing rectangle?
- does it completely fit the *y* range or do we have to split the existing rectangle in several pieces?
- does it simply extend the existing rectangle?

Then you will need to handle particular cases, like merging adjacent rectangles.

Another global approach, relying on the choice of slicing rectangles along the *y* axis, would be to list (and sort) all the horizontal lines, without really considering their bondaries, and then to loop on them by computing the borders created by the attached vertical edges. For each edge, you would have to note whether it is a left or a right edge, and check its *x* position relative to the other edges.

Answer (score 2):

Proposed algorithm, scanning vertically:

- Build a list of `(y, left, right, label, rectangle)` where `label` is either 'top' or 'bottom' and you have two elements in the list for each rectangle, one for the top of the rectangle and one for the bottom of the rectangle. Thus `left = rectangle.top_left.x` and `right = rectangle.bottom_right.x`, and `y` is either `rectangle.top_left.y` or `rectangle.bottom_right.y`.
- Sort this list in decreasing order of y.
- Maintain a set of active rectangles.
- Maintain two variables `current_min_left` and `current_max_right` of the active set.
- Maintain a variable `current_top`.
- Maintain a `result` list of rectangles, initially empty.
- Iterate on the sorted list of tops and bottoms.

  - When you encounter a new horizontal line: depending on its `left` and `right` and how they compare to `current_min_left` and `current_max_right` of the active set, add a rectangle to `result` if necessary.

    - For instance if the new line is `(y, left, right, 'top', r)` and `current_min_left <= left < current_max_right < right` then you should add `Rectangle(Point(current_min_left, current_top), Point(right, y))` to `result`.
    - When you add a rectangle to `result`, update `current_top` to the last encountered `y`.
  - When you encounter a new horizontal line: if it is a new top, add it to the active set. If it is a new bottom, remove the corresponding rectangle from the active set.